# Problem solving related to Object oriented programming concepts

Tags: oop

For quiet sometime now I have been working on improving my algo skills because its a requirement to clear interviews in companies like google, amazon etc. But recently I came across questions on object oriented programming concepts being asked in amazon interviews. I being a programmer in C doesn't know much about oops. Any sort of help like good books, links to improve these skills will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with the first edition of Tim Budd's "An Introduction to
Object-Oriented Programming". It was language agnostic, so I learned the concepts, not the implementations.

The [third edition](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~budd/Books/oopintro3e/info/ReadMe.html) is now out.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a grip on the OO concepts I would read some of the basic OO principles outlined by Robert Martin:

http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod

These principles really give Object Orientation a purpose and I bet would be excellent for any interview for a developer position.

Comment: And then once you get a grip on those principles reading the GoF OO design patterns will make a lot more sense since they are based on the basic OO principles that are outlined by Robert Martin

Answer (score 0):

Read the [GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOF) to start to truly understand design pattern solutions in OOP.

Comment: I'd skip it. Design patterns are not the same thing as OO concepts.

Comment: @Terry Wilcox: you are right. That's not the same. But reading that book helped me a lot in understanding how modeling solutions using objects, in order to take much advantage as possible from OOP.

Comment: If an interviewer asks you to explain polymorphism, the GoF book is going not going to save you.

Comment: @Terry Wilcox: I think I should keep my answer too. Look at the title: "Problem solving related to Object oriented programming concepts." Isn't GoF about problem solving with OOP?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest **"Head first"** series for beginners.

```
 1. Head first - OOAD 
 2. Head first - design patterns.
```

Once you feel you are comfortable with the concepts, you can read **`Gang of four book on Design patterns & OOAD`**